# Show moved/renamed files of Git repo

Tags: git, file-rename

I'm working in a large codebase that has recently been restructured, and many files are no longer where I expect them.

How can I see a list of files that were moved/renamed between two commits? I'm not interested in the changes to these or other files, just a view that maps old name to new name in some way.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: use `git diff --find-renames`, probably with `--diff-filter=R` and `--name-status`.

Git doesn't actually *store* renames.  It just stores *snapshots*.  Git can, however, compare two snapshots and—under your control and direction, to some extent—*deduce* that some file previous named `path/to/file` is now named `new/name/of/file`: i.e., that despite these being different files, they are also somehow the *same* file, much as a replica of the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) might *be* the Ship of Theseus even though it isn't.

Git's *rename detection* is enabled by adding `-M` or `--find-renames` to `git diff`, or is already enabled if you're using a modern version of `git diff`.  If you're using one of the underlying diff programs (`git diff-tree`, `git diff-index`, and so on) you need the explicit option.  You then have Git compare any two snapshots or other trees (such as the one represented by Git's index, or by your working tree) and it will do its best to find "sufficiently similar" files that have different *names*, and will then claim that such files must have been renamed.  (Note that it will do so even if, for instance, I just *delete* an old file, then create a new file with a new name that's sufficiently similar.)

"Sufficiently similar" here is tricky.  Git computes its so-called *similarity index* as a percentage, but the percentage of what is not well defined.<sup>1</sup>  Still, a file whose contents exactly match those of some previous file gets a 100% similarity index; a file that shares no bytes at all will get a 0% similarity index; and files that share *some* but not *all* bytes will get an index somewhere in between that will, at least in some vague sense, represent how similar the files are.

Git's default is to claim that file `path/to/file` was renamed to `new/name/of/file` upon finding that:

1. `path/to/file` is not present at all in the right side commit, while `new/name/of/file` is not present at all in the left side commit.  (The two "sides" are from the left and right commit hash or other specifiers you gave to `git diff`, e.g., `git diff a123456 b789abc` compares commit `a123456` on the left to commit `b789abc` on the right.)
2. The contents are similar.
3. No *other* pairing of otherwise unpaired left-and-right files are *more* similar.<sup>2</sup>
4. (Crucial) the similarity index meets or exceeds the *threshold* you specify on your command line.

The default threshold is 50% similar, if rename detection is enabled without setting a particular threshold.  The `-M` or `--find-renames` option takes an optional threshold value; if given, that sets the minimum threshold.

If no pairing meets the desired threshold, Git declares that the left-side file was deleted and the right-side file was newly added.  Otherwise, the paired-up similar files are removed from the list of potential pair-ups, and the remaining files are considered.  There is also a limit to the length of the queues of file names to be placed in these left and right side pairing-up pools, though for most cases you won't have to worry about this.

Having run all the files through the diff engine to find the right pairs, compute similarities if/as needed, and so on, Git will then diff the paired-up files as well, unless you suppress this with `--name-only` or `--name-status`.  As with the rename detection, this diff merely finds *a* way to transform the left-side file to match the right-side file.  This is not necessarily how any person did or would do it: it's just *a* way to get from left-side to right-side, preferably with a minimum of editing commands.

If you do use `--name-status`, Git will find each of the renames and present them in the output with a status code of `R`, followed by the similarity index that caused the pairing-up, and the two names (left and right side file-names complete with slashes).  (This also suppresses the content diff, as noted above.)  If you add `--diff-filter=R` to your `git diff` command, you can tell Git to print *only* renamed files.  There are more filtering options available; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for details.

---

<sup>1</sup>The algorithm uses the delta compression code to find byte sequences that would be retained if one file were delta-compressed against the other, and byte sequences that would simply be introduced as "new bytes".  If I recall correctly, this also strips carriage returns so that CRLF changes in text files does not count against the similarity index, but I might be mis-remembering.  In any case these are then divided by the overall file size, to come up with the similarity index value.

<sup>2</sup>To break ties, the tree code used to add 1 to the computed similarity index if the new file name ends with the same final path *component*.  That is, suppose we find a 75% similarity from `old/path/name` to both `new/name` and `new/xyz`.  This gives us a tie: did the file get renamed from `old/path/name` to `new/name`, or to `new/xyz`?  The string `xyz` does not match the string `name`, but the two `name` parts do match, so this one gets a 1% bonus.

Since the time I looked at this code, Git has gotten smarter about internal *directory* renames: that is, if it seems that `path/to/file` became `path/four/file` and `path/to/X` became `path/four/X`, it starts looking like `to`—a directory name—must have become `X`.  If the pattern repeats for every `path/to`, then indeed, a directory rename is the way to represent this.  This kind of rename detection is much better and eliminates the need for a 1% bonus, provided Git actually pairs up all the old and new files in advance.